# Balloontip how can I catch a click C#

Tags: c#, windows, popup, click, balloon

I'm trying to create a balloontip (windows popup) and want to know if the user clicks on it. But I can't catch the click.

I've already tried a few things but it won't work.

```
notification.ShowBalloonTip(5000);          
notification.BalloonTipClicked += new System.EventHandler(this.OpenWindow);
notification.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.OpenWindow);
notification.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.OpenWindow);
```

The `notification` is a NotifyIcon object. I hope someone here can help me with this.

Comment: Did you try using MessageBox? With the help of DialogResult?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try using a MessageBox, but it just won't open the function. I think it does jump over it. And I have no idea how to solve that.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Actually the code works fine for the `BalloonTipClicked` event. Do not forget to set `notification.Visible = true;` and, obviously the `BalloonTipText`; also the `Icon`, maybe `notification.Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information;`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There where multiple things I had to do.
I needed `notification.BalloonTipClicked` to verify I've clicked on the balloon.

Also, afther that line of code I had a `notification.dispose` function to remove the icon. But this was comming to fast, so the notification was disposed before I could click on it.

The solution to save that problem was to set the visibility to false.

After that it worked fine!